# Return in recursive function php

Tags: php, recursion, return

I've got a little problem with recursive function output. Here's the code:

```
function getTemplate($id) {
    global $templates;
    $arr = $templates[$id-1];
    if($arr['parentId'] != 0) {
        $arr['text'] .= str_replace($arr['attr'], $arr['text'], getTemplate($arr['parentId']));
    }
    return $arr['text']; 
}
```

The problem is that that function returns a value on each iteration like this:

> file.exe 
>   category / file.exe 
>   root / category / file.exe

And I need only the last string which resembles full path. Any suggestions?

//UPD: done, the problem was with the dot in `$arr['text'] .= str_replace`

Comment: what is `$templates` - example?

Comment: @sashkello it is sure a recursive function, because it calls itself.

Comment: if you are working with directories and files have a look at RecursiveDirectoryIterator() http://php.net/manual/es/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: @sash - a function that calls itself must be under the term recursive

Comment: This code would be much *much* better if it didn't use a global. There's no need for it, and it adds unnecessary complication.

Comment: return when you complete your process like if($pros == completed) return ;

Comment: @davidkonrad the $templates is an array with arrays inside, like array("id"=>2,"parentId"=>1,"attr"=>"<%TITLE%>","text"=>"folder / <%CONTENT%>"),

Comment: A recursive function is any function which calls itself multiple times till the condition becomes false. So the above function is recursive.

Comment: Posting an dump of the `$templates` variable would be helpful

Comment: Self-declared typo question based on OP's edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please. I know its using global variable but I think this should work

```
$arrGlobal = array();

function getTemplate($id) {
    global $templates;
    global $arrGlobal;

    $arr = $templates[$id-1];
    if($arr['parentId'] != 0) {
       array_push($arrGlobal, getTemplate($arr['parentId']));
    }
    return $arr['text'];
}

$arrGlobal = array_reverse($arrGlobal);

echo implode('/',$arrGlobal);
```

Comment: i've found the problem in my code, it was the dot in  $arr['text'] .= thanks for your response, it worked too ;)

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) Can you mark my solution as useful so it may help some one else

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function getTemplate($id) {
    global $templates;
    $arr = $templates[$id-1];
    if($arr['parentId'] != 0) {
    return $arr['text'] .= str_replace($arr['attr'], $arr['text'], getTemplate($arr['parentId']));
    }
}
```

Comment: that function outputs the same thing without the last string which i need.

Comment: One thing I want to know, does $arr['parentId'] != 0 means it will stop iterating here ?

Comment: $arr['parentId']=0 means that this is the root folder; we don't need to go deeper and the function start replacing the text.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
function getTemplate($id, array $templates = array())
{
  $index = $id - 1;
  if (isset($templates[$index])) {
    $template = $templates[$index];
    if (isset($template['parentId']) && $template['parentId'] != 0) {
      $parent = getTemplate($template['parentId'], $templates);
      $template['text'] .= str_replace($template['attr'], $template['text'], $parent);
    }
    return $template['text'];
  }
  return '';
}

$test = getTemplate(123, $templates);

echo $test;
```

Comment: same result with my function, returns on each iteration

Comment: @bigbobr In my example `$test` will hold the entire string. The function will need to return each value in order to be used recursively. Please update your question showing where you are using the function. It shouldn't be used within a loop or you will overwrite the value of `$test` on each iteration.